# Windows 7 Copying Issue

Tags: c#, windows-7

After being launched from a share my program is then copying to the local computer under %temp%. This works exactly as I want it to in Windows 10, however this is in an environment with Windows 7 computers too.

Initially I had just **File.Copy** as my way of copying the file to %temp%, after some testing I found the second method to work at creating a file, but I can't create my *.exe, the file is removed from the system immediately after I am finished with it.

*I refer to the location as %temp% but I really mean the equivalent of it*

How I set the location to the temp file location
    Path.GetTempPath() 
Windows 10

```
File.Copy(src, dest)
```

Windows 7

```
FileInfo srcInfo = new FileInfo(src);
FileStream srcStream = srcInfo.OpenRead();
FileStream destStream = File.Create(dest);
srcStream.CopyTo(destStream);
destStream.Close();
srcStream.Close();
```

*I have also tried alternate formats for reading, creating and writing to the file like declaring it with the FileStream*

I have been looking into other methods of accomplishing the same task however I can't find a method which works for me and all answers I have found are very outdated.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to compile the application and writing this in .NET 4.5

My application has been tested running without the copy and copying to other locations and it works fine. It is just to the user profile. I have tested running it through Group Policy, as Administrator and as a normal user.

A suitable answer would be one which details a more appropriate File location unaffected by the Windows 7 UAC or a solution to my issue described.

Comment: *the file is removed from the system immediately after I am finished with it.* This is typically because antivirus/malware detection software deletes unsigned executables that just appear out of nowhere. It may also be because Windows is configured to delete files from %TEMP% when they're closed, because %TEMP% is supposed to be used for temporary files, not persistent files. That's why it has *TEMP* in the name. :-)

Comment: Perhaps you can use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) to find suitable save location.

Comment: I will start with adding an Exception to our AV and then try again. My only thought was that it runs absolutely fine on Windows 10, we manage the systems the exact same so the AV should act the same on both 7 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative you could test:

```
var bSource = File.ReadAllBytes(src);
File.WriteAllBytes(dest, bSource);
```

But it sounds more like an AV issue.

Comment: That didn't solve anything for me. I did some testing on a basic machine without AV, GPO's active or otherwise management it still gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

@Wubbler mentioned using Environment.SpecialFolder I used this method to run in a very general location. Although my application was signed, my test computer was very poor apparently.

After returning to work I was able to test on the original machine, I added exclusions for myapp.exe and in my case it was a Process I needed to exclude.

Implementing both these aspects I now have things running well. I had another issue with deployment and it was a UNC reference for a GPO user Logon item. I determined my link here was broken so I wrote a script to map the server location, launch the app then delete the mapping.

```
net use Y: /delete /y
net use Y: \\TE-ADMIN\netlogon /persistent:y
"Y:\TEG System Helper.exe"
net use Y: /delete /y
```